# Typeclass-style default methods with algebraic data types involved?

Tags: haskell

I'm coming from Standard ML, and am new to Haskell so I'm still trying to wrap my head around the elaborate type system. I want to make a module exposing an algebraic datatype `Expression a` along with some functions that can be used with values of the type `Expression a`. That alone isn't too bad. Small caveat: I want to restrict the type `a` to be in the `Num` typeclass so the functions can work with `a` values as numbers. Still not too bad; after some poking around, I believe what I want to use for this is called a "GADT".

Bigger caveat: so for the most part, the functions can be defined the same for all types in the `Num` typeclass. However, I want a few cases of a few of the functions to have some alternate behavior if `a` is in the `Integral` type class, and some alternate behavior if `a` is in the `Fractional` type class. For the most part though, everything is the same for all `Num` types so I don't want to have to rewrite everything separately for general case, `Integral`, and `Fractional`, as that would result in a lot of duplicate code.

To my understanding this is called "Ad hoc polymorphism", which is something Haskell supports through the typeclass system. However, this appears to be more complicated for two reasons: 1, this is an ADT whose constructors must be used in the default functions as well as in the `Integral`-specific and `Fractional`-specific alternatives. 2, `Integral` and `Fractional` are typeclasses (not types) so I'm not sure if this makes it harder to make specific behavior for them.

Again, I'm new to Haskell, so it's possible I'm thinking about this all wrong.

Edit for clarification. The difficulty all boils down to: I want to make a default behavior for Nums, and then an alternate behavior if the Num happens to be an Integral and a different alternate behavior if the Num happens to be a Fractional.

Comment: it would be helpful if you gave an SML example that you would like to implement in Haskell.

Comment: @ErikR That's a good idea -- I haven't really thought about how I would implement this in SML, so thinking about that would probably help me figure this out and communicate it better.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First off, what you want to do with the restriction of `a` to `Num` doesn't require anything nearly as elaborate as GADTs. If you have your type `Expression a` and a function `exprFunc`, you can declare it as follows.

```
exprFunc :: Num a => Expression a -> Expression a
```

With this, `exprFunc` will only except arguments that are `Num`s. As for your second question, the only (accepted) way to do polymorphic functions in Haskell is through typeclasses. So, for your example with `Integral` and `Fractional`, the best way would be to do the following.

```
class Num a => C a where
    exprMethod :: Expression a -> Expression a
```

Now, you can define two separate definitions of `exprMethod` for `Fractional`s and `Integral`s.

```
instance Fractional a => C a where
    exprMethod expr = <some code>

instance Integral a => C a where
    exprMethod expr = <some other code>
```

Comment: Thanks! Just to clarify: would a user of the module see the name/type of the typeclass -- and so should I switch to making all my functions part of the typeclass rather than directly in the module? I guess my main concern is that it seems weird for some functions to be defined directly as part of the module and some to be defined as members of a typeclass exported by the module, when really the user of the module uses both the same way...

Comment: Would a user of the module see that some functions involve the type `C a` and some don't? What should `C` be in this case -- it's the name of the typeclass right? I'm assuming it shouldn't also be `Expression`?

Comment: @vijrox I'm not entirely certain what you mean by users seeing the "name/type of the typeclass". However, defining some things as functions and some things as methods is a very common and accepted practice in Haskell.

Comment: Yes, users of the module would see the constraint `C a` in some functions and not in others. On the other hand, they would have to see something. I mean, if a function only works for `Integrals` and `Fractionals`, then the type `Num a => Expression a -> Expression a` is obviously incorrect. You need something to specify that extra restriction. In this case, that would be `C a`.

Comment: Ah I see what you mean. One thing I was hoping I could do: rather than making the function work *only* for `Integrals` and `Fractionals`, I wanted to make a default behavior for `Nums`, and then an alternate behavior if the `Num` happens to be an `Integral` and a different alternate behavior if the `Num` happens to be a `Fractional`. Am I trying to do something reasonable here? This way, the user doesn't need to see the typeclass `C a` (and preferably wouldn't see it, for the sake of abstraction)

Comment: Sadly, that kind of typeclass overriding isn't currently supported. You could open a feature request for a GHC language extension, but until then, you'll have to either take a look at a dependently typed language, like Idris, or find another way to implement it.

Comment: Thanks! That's exactly what I was looking to have answered.

Comment: @Kwarrtz GHC won't let you have instances like that because it doesn't fit with the way instance resolution works. Here, the both of the instance heads are `C a`, which makes them duplicate instances (which is not allowed with `OVERLAPPING` pragmas or even the `IncoherentInstances` extension). The reason is that, when a instance needs to be chosen, it first looks for a matching instance head. That chosen instance is "set in stone" at this point, so to speak (GHC is determined to try to use this instance). Next, it checks the instance constraint. If the constraint fails, the type check fails.